# Docking a form that is on a separate UI thread

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, winforms

I already have code to create a main form, and to create a "child" form with its own message pump. At the moment the child is completely independent of the main form.

I would like to dock the child form inside the parent form so that moving/resizing/etc the parent will also affect the child.  What is the easiest or best way to do this?  I know that normally you would dock a control, but a separate message pump requires a window.

As for why I'm doing this: the main form has multiple graph controls, and painting all of these on one thread gets slow when the graphs get complex. I can't increase performance any further without breaking out each graph's paint into its own thread. I believe this is one of the few situations where using multiple UI threads is valid?

Comment: What is the relative positions and rectangles of your child compared to your parent form? Of course this should be described with some screen shot.

Comment: Displaying a form on another thread is already *very* questionable in Winforms, the SystemEvents class causes serious problems when it fires its events on the wrong thread.  Lots of controls subscribe the UserPreferenceChanged event.  You dig yourself a much deeper hole by trying to dock such a window, that requires messaging with the parent.  Don't do it.

Comment: @HansPassant am I supposed to just give up then?  Can you think of any solution that does not involve separate UI threads?  We plan on moving to WPF, which will hopefully enable a better solution to this problem, but I could really do with a solution in the meantime.

Comment: There just isn't any reasonable scenario where a graph ever needs so much time to draw itself that you need such drastic hacks.  There just are not enough pixels on a monitor.  Surely the real problem is that you stuff way too much data into it.  Of course WPF doesn't solve that either.

Answer (score 0):

After some experimentation, it appears this is not possible.

Attempting to set the child's `Parent` results in the exception *'controls created on one thread cannot be parented to a control on a different thread.'*